# Split Configurable Products' options onto two pages

Tags: product, magento2.3, theme, workflow

A particular Product has eight configurable attributes. The logical flow from a user perspective would be to select the first four attributes on one page, click "Next", then select the last four attributes on a second page.

**Does Magento have any facility for enabling this type of flow?** I am considering implementing this completely in the theme, but perhaps Magento has a preferable way of configuring this.

Answer (score 1):

Magento doesn't support any similar features out of the box and doesn't provide any designed solution or preferable way to do it.

I don't suggest you to try a split this functionality into 2 pages. This is possible but will be costly. You can solve this with split your logical groups of custom options into 2 steps (like tabs) and just implement some cover with theme template changes and JS processing.

Better to keep all options in the same form and using core logic of add product to cart with all populated options. You can hide or disable product "add to cart" button until customer will filled all required data.

You also can almost easily extend custom options in admin with additional parameters to solve correct order and groupping into tabs

Comment: Thank you, I will consider implementing the functionality as "tabs" on a single page load, hiding and displaying divs as necessary.